# Spark Cassandra connector base simple program getting spark logging error

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra

I was trying a very basic hello world program for java+spark+cassandra.

Initially I had some mixed versions of libraries which caused the NoSuchMethodError (#5). When I got the versions right, I get the noclassdefound error for spark logging (#4). This is from the cassandra connector code. I have built it from the b2.3 branch of  github which is only couple of commits behind the master(using sbt).

All solutions for spark logging issue point to moving to older versions. This is not a practical solution for us as we need to figure this out for future development.
Wonder why the latest stable build of cassandra connector refers to spark logging which is no longer available now??. 
Any help is appreciated.

**Spark version: 2.3.0
Cassandra: 3.9.0**

The relevant code snippet is pasted below.

```
   #1 SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("appname")
        .setMaster("local");
   #2 sparkConf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1"); 

   #3 JavaSparkContext ctx = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);

   #4 CassandraConnector connector = CassandraConnector.apply(ctx.getConf()); <<<< org/apache/spark/logging noclassdeffound error

   #5 try (Session session = connector.openSession()) { <<< nosuchmethoderror: scala.runtime.objectref.zero()lscala/runtime/objectref
```

The POM is below

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    com.mygroup
    apache-spark
    1.0-SNAPSHOT
    jar
    apache-spark
    http://maven.apache.org

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId> 
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency> 

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector-java_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0-M1</version>
    </dependency>  
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
        <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.thrift</groupId>
        <artifactId>libthrift</artifactId>
        <version>0.11.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <org.apache.spark.spark-core.version>2.2.1</org.apache.spark.spark-core.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing to fix is

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector-java_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.0-M1</version>
</dependency>
```

Which does not match any of your other build versions. The Java module was merged into the main artifact. You also shouldn't include the java driver module on it's own since this will most likely have issue with guava inclusions.

Take a look at

https://github.com/datastax/SparkBuildExamples/blob/master/scala/maven/oss/pom.xml for example pom files.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I removed the java connector dependency and got rid of the spark logging issue but I am back to this issue:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.runtime.ObjectRef.zero()Lscala/runtime/ObjectRef;
 at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$.com$datastax$spark$connector$cql$CassandraConnector$$createSession(CassandraConnector.scala)

Comment: Next problem is spark sql is at 2.3 while all other spark libs are at 2.2.1

Comment: If you go to 2.3 you will need the spark Cassandra connector 2.3 as well

Comment: Hello Russ. I am using Cassandra Connector 2.3 already. I will try switching all spark libs to 2.3. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, that helped to fix it. The dependency minefield is   bit harder than usual :)